# Google Calendar / Exchange / Outlook Web Access sync

Tags: linux, sync, exchange, calendar, google-calendar

May be impossible but..

My firm uses Exchange Server (version 5 I think), with no POP3/IMAP access.
So when I'm out of the office, it is down to Outlook Web Access.
And my laptop is running Ubuntu, so it is a pretty poor experience.

What I would like is for my Outlook calendar to sync itself with my Google calendar (or with anything Linux).

Comment: I was going to ask same question, but with some picture on it :P http://www.theemailadmin.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/office-outlook-web-access-21.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [davmail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/) - it allows access to your exchange calendar via ical. The way I use it :

- configure davmail with my corporate outlook
- In thunderbird (I am to TB3 beta) , create a calendar (iCal) which points to the davmail configuration

Now, I can access outlook via thunderbird.

Not sure if this solves your problem, as it does not by default "syncs" to google etc.

Comment: Don't know 1 year ago how was davmail, but today it does solve the op's problem full featured! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into [Google Calendar Sync](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=de&answer=89955).
I use it to sync my Google Calendar with my Outlook at work. I do not know if it works with the Web Access variant of Outlook, though.

Comment: Doesn't work through web access as far as I can tell. It needs a proper Outlook install.